# 【monaco-editor】When I send a request in provideInlineCompletions, it will cause the editor to report an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, monaco-editor

```
async.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) Canceled: Canceled 
at Listener.invoke 
at PrivateEventDeliveryQueue.deliver  
at Emitter.fire  at MutableToken.cancel 
at CancellationTokenSource.cancel 
at Object.cancel 
at UpdateOperation.dispose 
at MutableDisposable.dispose  
at dispose
```

Causing the code I obtained to not render properly

I want to render the code normally